# React injecting meta tags into the head using next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to add `<meta />` tags into the head of a `nextjs` `_app.tsx` component ( For none next js  users it is a component that is at the top level of the tree )

When I put this component in the head only the first 5 of 9 meta tags get put into the head and the others are lost.

If I change the order of the meta tags the first 5 still go into the head and other others are lost.

Why is this happening and what can I do to get these tags into the head?

```
import * as React from 'react'

export const MyLovelyComp = ({data}) => {

  return (
    <>
      <meta name="someName" content={data.informationCode1} />
      <meta name="someOtherName" content={data.informationCode2} />
      <meta name="someOtherOtherName" content={data.informationCode3} />
      <meta name="someName1" content={data.informationCode1} />
      <meta name="someOtherName1" content={data.informationCode2} />
      <meta name="someOtherOtherName1" content={data.informationCode3} />
      <meta name="someName2" content={data.informationCode1} />
      <meta name="someOtherName2" content={data.informationCode2} />
      <meta name="someOtherOtherName2" content={data.informationCode3} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Then used like this:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
  // ...
<Head>
    <MyLovelyComp data={lovelydata} />
</Head>
 // ...
```

Comment: hi , can you please attach screenshot of page source, where these tags appear.